# JQM vs Bootstrap, pagebeforeshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, jquery-mobile

Приложение в Intel XDK. Как известно, они убрали поддержку фреймворка `JQM` и оставили только Bootrstrap3.

Нужен эвент типа `$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page", func()`.
Он нужен для подготовки страниц, вызова ajax-функций для динамического содержимого и другой полезной логики приложения.

Что можно использовать в bootstrap3 вместо `pagebeforeshow`, который был только в Jquery Mobile? Причем добавлять Jquery Mobile поздновато, портит все отображение страниц. И все равно не работает, если и добавить.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow in Russian! As the name implies, Russian is the working language of this site. Please either translate your question into Russian or [ask the same question on StackOverflow in English](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Your question may be closed soon, but it will most likely be reopened if you choose to translate it.

Comment: В `ready` уже поздно будет?

Answer (score 2):

```
$.holdReady( true );
$.getScript( "myplugin.js", function() {
  $.holdReady( false );
});
```

[jQuery.holdReady](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/)

Comment: а каким образом ваш ответ решает задачу автора? не могли бы подробнее ответить на вопрос?

Comment: если я правильно понял задачу, то нужно до начала отрисовки страницы выполнить некие скрипты, загрузить скрипты... если задача не в этом тогда мой ответ не подойдет.

Comment: спасибо. Думаю такое решение могло бы подойти ТС.